# Google line chart not displaying milliseconds correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to graph some data on a line chart over a timed race, and so the timeofday datatype seemed like the correct type to use. However whenever I plot the time, the milliseconds aren't displaying correctly. Time of day is an array consisting of [Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds]

For example the data below:

```
[
    [[0,0,0, 1],0,1],
    [[0,0,1,10],1,1],
    [[0,0,2,15],2,1]
]
```

Would generate times looking like this:

**00:00:00..999, 00:00:01..990, 00:00:02..985**

I'm plotting the data with a datatable, using the addRows function

It looks as though the milliseconds are kind of inverted (e.g. 1000 - x) and there's the extra decimal point between the seconds and the milliseconds.

My googling hasn't found anything on this so far. Am I missing something simple? Is this an issue with a timeofday being the domain?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

seems to work fine here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'B');
    data.addRows([
      [[0,0,0,1],0,1],
      [[0,0,1,10],1,1],
      [[0,0,2,15],2,1]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {pointSize: 4});
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

running the above produces the following row values...

0) `00:00:00.001`
1) `00:00:01.010`
2) `00:00:02.015`

Comment: is there more you can share? which version is loaded? any relevant chart options?

Comment: This is weird, I ran your code right here using the run code snippet and I get the same thing! I'm running safari, I'll try in another browser.

Comment: Yeah same thing in chrome... I'll try a different OS (currently on OSX 10.11.6)

Comment: fyi: i'm using latest Chrome Version: 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: Cheers for your help btw. I tried ubuntu 16.04 in firefox, same deal. It's all minified, so it's hard to step through what's happening.

Comment: i've seen other issues with this column type as well, definitely buggy...